# Heroku node.js API timing out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mean-stack

I have had an application running on heroku for over a year with no issues. It is a simple MEAN application which pulls some data from the API and displays it on the website.

Since 2 days(and no changes in code for months). I am getting a 503 time-out error code.

I have tried testing the API with Postman and I get the same issue. Running the application locally works perfectly fine. And I tried querying the database directly from a console which works as well. Anyone have an idea what the issue could be. The code for my ENDPOINT routes:

```
app.get("/api/protocols", function(req, res){
    Protocol.find(function(err, protocols){
        if(err){
           res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(protocols);
    });
});

app.get("/api/diagnostics", function(req, res){
    Diagnostic.find(function(err, protocols){
        if(err){
           res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(protocols);
    });
});

app.get('/api/references', function(req, res){
    Reference.find(function(err, references){
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(references);
    });
});
```

and the code for the very simple api:
angular.module('ProtocolService', []).factory('protocolService', function($http) {

```
function getProtocols(){
    return $http.get('/api/protocols');
}

return {getProtocols: getProtocols};
```

});

Part of Heroku log showing the h12 failure on the 3 api endpoints:

```
2018-04-17T11:24:57.082451+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/references" host=emctreatment.herokuapp.com request_id=44410e1e-7249-47d4-a927-90c840f229f7 fwd="213.127.92.1" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2018-04-17T11:24:57.081331+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/protocols" host=emctreatment.herokuapp.com request_id=658d91ca-8f7e-4ad1-b8c3-6618b25abfe8 fwd="213.127.92.1" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2018-04-17T11:25:11.244476+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/diagnostics" host=emctreatment.herokuapp.com request_id=b560d69d-c689-42c8-b18e-565f2addf6da fwd="213.127.92.1" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2018-04-17T11:25:27.214363+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/protocols" host=emctreatment.herokuapp.com request_id=ba945119-a1df-4d0b-8b91-5d2c9062a79f fwd="213.127.92.1" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2018-04-17T11:25:27.209571+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/references" host=emctreatment.herokuapp.com request_id=db3459b6-f3a6-4c19-a943-c9f43394e92e fwd="213.127.92.1" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Protocol Scheme:

```
// grab the mongoose module
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// define the Protocol model
// module.exports allows us to pass this to other files when it is called
module.exports = mongoose.model('Protocol', {
    PROTOCOL : String,
    CLASS    : String,
    Localisation: String,
    T       : String,
    N       : String,
    Treatment : String,
    considerations : String

});
```

Diagnostic Scheme

```
    // grab the mongoose module
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    // define the Protocol model
    // module.exports allows us to pass this to other files when it is called
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Diagnostic', {
        Localisation    : String,
        T               : String,
        N               : String,
        ClinExams       : String,
        RadioPrim       : String,
        RadioNeck       : String,
        RadioDist       : String,
        Extra           : String,
        Paramedics      : String,
        Considerations  : String

    });
```

Reference Scheme:

```
    // grab the mongoose module
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// define the Reference model
// module.exports allows us to pass this to other files when it is called
module.exports = mongoose.model('Reference', {
    CLASS    : String,
    TEXT     : String,
    TDEF     : String,
    NDEF     : String

});
```

Server.js file:

```
// modules =================================================
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
var mongoose       = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

// configuration ===========================================

// config files
var db = require('./config/db');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set our port
var url = process.env.DATABASEURL || db.url;
mongoose.connect(url); // connect to our mongoDB database (commented out after you enter in your own credentials)

// get all data/stuff of the body (POST) parameters
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json 
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request. simulate DELETE/PUT
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users

// routes ==================================================
require('./app/routes')(app); // pass our application into our routes

// start app ===============================================
app.listen(port);   
console.log('Application running on port ' + port);             // shoutout to the user
exports = module.exports = app;                         // expose app
```

Comment: Can you provide logs from heroku? It'd be good to know which endpoint is hanging and where it reaches in the code when it then hangs and returns a 503. No one can run your code as it depends on a bunch of code you haven't provided (such as the Protocol, Reference, and Diagnostic modules).

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn edited to show logs